# Android Native crash at in tgkill and Native crash at in abort

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports, google-play-console

In play console  I get two crash reports  `Native crash in tgkill`, and `Native crash in abort` - these reports come form android 7, 7.1, 8.0. devices. The crash reports do not include any lines from my code.

My questions are:

1) What do these error means ?

2) How do I recover from this type of crash and what changes should I make to my code in order to prevent them from happening?